# Modfying existing excel using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When I am modifying the existing excel file in server and copy to local machine and open it, I am getting **`excel could not open because some content is unreadable, do you want to open and repair this workbook?`** Below is my code. Can someone please suggest me how to avoid this kind of scenario?

```
File f = new File(directory+"users.xlsx");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);

workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Row row = sheet.getRow(4);
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
Cell cell = row1.getCell(i);
cell.setCellValue(formattedDate);
cell.setCellStyle(normalStyle);
}

 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f, false);
               workbook.write(out);
               out.close();
```

Have been trying to resolve for 8 hours, without luck. Would be thankful if someone can shed light on this.

Comment: Try to read using WoorkbookFactory.create(fileInputStream)  and use another File in the new FileOutputStream(f, false); instead of "f" use another file. I should work.

Comment: @Koitoer Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the output to a different file, dont forget to close the input and output
  and use this  http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html

```
File f = new File(directory+"users.xlsx");

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);

Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileInputStream);
fileInputStream.close();
sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Row row = sheet.getRow(4);
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
Cell cell = row1.getCell(i);
cell.setCellValue(formattedDate);
cell.setCellStyle(normalStyle);
}

 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f, false);
               workbook.write(out);
               out.close();
```

Comment: I want to modify the existing file because I am using it in code to access it. I can't change name every time because the name is used in code in File(). Please suggest

Comment: So, the only thing I need to change is to use WorkBookFactory?

Comment: WorkBookFactory doesn't contain a method of such type--

Comment: It is create not createWorkbook, my bad